# How to fetch a MySQL table field value in a numeric PHP variable to use it in an IF statement?

Tags: php, mysql, variables, fetch

I have a MySQL table 'log' with columns 'idUser', 'password', 'priority'. Depending on the 'priority' value (1 or 2) I try to access different PHP pages from the login.php page. I don't know how to store the value of 'priority' in a PHP variable, for using it in an IF statement:

```
$_SESSION['username'] = $user;
$_SESSION['password'] = $pass;
$sql = "SELECT priority FROM log WHERE idUser = '$user' AND password = '$pass'";
$p = mysql_query($sql);
$r = mysql_fetch_row($p);
 <!--?? -->  
if ($r==1)
{header('Location: page1.php');}
else
{header('Location: page2.php');}
```

Comment: should be `if ($r['priority']==1)`

Comment: It doesn't work, It says "Undefined index: priority"

Comment: Be aware that if `$user` or `$pass` come from user input, they will need to be escaped, otherwise you will have a SQL injection vulnerability here. It would be even better to switch to a new MySQL database library, so you can use parameterisation (and thus not need to worry about escaping).

Comment: Also, it is not thought to be safe to store passwords in plaintext - they need hashing, even if your project only needs low levels of security.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, the mysql_* functions have been deprecated and replaced with the mysqli_* functions.

for your question however, in your if statement $r is an array so whatever column you want needs to be addressed as such $r['priority'] or $r[2] or whatever the index of that column is

here is your code corrected:

```
$_SESSION['username'] = $user;
$_SESSION['password'] = $pass;
$sql = "SELECT priority FROM log WHERE idUser = '$user' AND password = '$pass'";
$p = mysql_query($sql);
$r = mysql_fetch_row($p);
 <!--?? -->  
if ($r[0]==1)
{header('Location: page1.php');}
else
{header('Location: page2.php');}
```

Comment: Thank you! But it doesn't work as I want. Maybe the function mysql_fetch_row() is not the one... I don't need an array statement, $r I need to be a numeric value (1 or 2). So now, there are no errors, but IF statement doesn't work, only page2.php is accessible as at the first login 'priority' was 2. I don't know where is the mistake!

Comment: @LuminitaDuta what do you store in the column `priority` ?

Comment: @LuminitaDuta could you var_dump($r) and show your result, if the column 'priority' has a 1 in it, the if statement should catch it

Comment: I store TinyInt variable, with values 1 and 2. If the user has priority 1, after pressing the submitt button from the login page, he will see page1.php, if the user has priority 2, he will see page2.php. Something is missing in my code, I don't know what, maybe a loop?

Comment: It says "Undefined index: priority"; I'am so bad in PHP, even as beginner!

Comment: in the if statement change $r['priority'] to $r[0] and do the same please

Comment: THANK YOU, CumminUp07!!! I love you! It worked! I tried this for a day now! Thanks a lot!

Comment: you can show appreciation by accepting the answer, your welcome

Comment: I tried to vote but I have no sufficient reputation for. I'm really sorry!